# how to enable debug logs in stdout for logstash?

Tags: debugging, stdout, logstash

I'm struggling as newbie in logstash, below is some info of my env

```
Logstash Version: logstash-7.16.2-1.x86_64
java Version: openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19 LTS
```

## Logstash Conf

```
input {
  stdin { }
}
output {
  stdout {
    debug => true
    }
}
```

I run logstash with below command, I get error:

```
# /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f simple.conf

[ERROR] 2022-01-03 08:26:36.742 [Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>] stdout - Unknown setting 'debug' for stdout
```

how do I enable debug logs in logstash, outputting events, as well as message section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For debuging you cannot use debug, you would have to use **rubydebug** as bellow:

```
output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug {
      metadata => true # This makes the logs to appear in console
    }
  }
}
```